# When the probability of a set equals one

Tags: probability, measure-theory

This might be a stupid question, but here it goes.

Let $A \subseteq \Omega$ and $P(A) = 1$. Can we conclude that $A = \Omega$? If not, is there an example where $A \neq \Omega$?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you might want to look up the term "almost surely".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $\Omega =\{1,2\}$, $P\{1\}=1, P\{2\}=0$ and $A=\{1\}$.

Comment: Of course, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set $\Omega=\{1,2\}$ and $A=\{1\}$, and define $p(\{1\})=1, p(\{2\})=0$. You can see that $p$ is indeed a probability, and $A\neq Q$.

Another example is $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $A=[0,1)$, and the standard ("uniform") probability on $[0,1]$, for example.